# Platinum vs Silver as Electrode for carbonic acid electrolyte

Tags: electrochemistry

Is silver a better cathode electrode with carbonic acid in a galvanic cell or is a platinum electrode better with carbonic acid ? The anode electrode is copper with copper sulfate electrolyte, and the salt bridge is sodium chloride.

Comment: sorry it should say platinum based electrode

Comment: Platinum based? What do you mean?

Comment: an electrode made from platinum. A platinum electrode